# Creating a form with spring and list of bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I know there are similar questions to mine but I can't make it work. But please bear with me.

Here is my bean

```
public class FLTQuestionnaireBean
{
    private int myQuestionId;
    private int myQuestionNum;
    private String myQuestion;
    private String myQuestionAnswer;
    private String myQuestionType;
    private String myQuestionModule;
    private String myQuestionStrand;
    private String myQuestionDifficulty;

    // getters and setters here
}
```

And my wrapper class:

```
public class QuestionnaireBeanWrapper
{
    private List<FLTQuestionnaireBean> myQuestionnaireBeanList;

    public void add( FLTQuestionnaireBean questionnaireBean )
    {
        myQuestionnaireBeanList.add( questionnaireBean );
    }

        //getter and setter here
}
```

**EDIT: change modelAttribute from ${ wrapper } to  "wrapper"**
Spring form

```
<form:form id="reading-form" action="../index/FLT_evaluate_reading.do" method="POST" modelAttribute="wrapper">
     <c:forEach items="${ wrapper.questionnaireBeanList }" varStatus="i">
           <form:input path="questionnaireBeanList[${i.index}].questionId" type="text"/>
           <form:input path="questionnaireBeanList[${i.index}].questionNum" type="text"/>
           <form:input path="questionnaireBeanList[${i.index}].question" type="text"/>
           <form:input path="questionnaireBeanList[${i.index}].questionAnswer" type="text"/>
           <form:input path="questionnaireBeanList[${i.index}].questionType" type="text"/>
           <form:input path="questionnaireBeanList[${i.index}].questionModule" type="text"/>
           <form:input path="questionnaireBeanList[${i.index}].questionStrand" type="text"/>
           <form:input path="questionnaireBeanList[${i.index}].questionDifficulty" type="text"/>
      </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/index/FLT", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String indexFLT( @RequestParam( defaultValue = "" )
String message, @RequestParam( defaultValue = "" )
String messageType, ModelMap model )
{
    model.addAttribute( "message", message );
    model.addAttribute( "messageType", messageType );

    QuestionnaireBeanWrapper wrapper = new QuestionnaireBeanWrapper();
    wrapper.add( new FLTQuestionnaireBean() );
    wrapper.add( new FLTQuestionnaireBean() );

    model.addAttribute( "wrapper", wrapper );

    return "als-questionnaire/flt";
}
```

I'm getting an exception when I run the app. I'm getting the error starting at first `<form:input..` heres my stacktrace:

**EDIT: Change of stactrace**

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'com' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
...
```

**Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? I really need help. Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
<form:form id="reading-form" action="../index/FLT_evaluate_reading.do" method="POST" modelAttribute="${ wrapper }">
```

to

```
<form:form id="reading-form" action="../index/FLT_evaluate_reading.do" method="POST" modelAttribute="wrapper">
```

The `form` tag's `modelAttribute` element needs the name of the model attribute, not the object itself (or rather its `toString()` result), which you get from `${wrapper}`.

The hint was

> Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name **'com'**

I am sure if you do

```
wrapper.toString()
```

and print the result in your controller, you will see something like

```
com.somepackage.QuestionnaireBeanWrapper
```

It tries to use that to resolve the model attribute, resolving each token before a `.`, failing on the first it doesn't find in the `Model` attributes. In this case, there is nothing called `com` in the `Model` attributes, so it complains and fails.

Comment: I updated my post. I applied the changes as you suggested but there still a stacktrace. I also print the `wrapper.toString()` and yes it prints like this `com.neu.als.thesis.db.beans.QuestionnaireBeanWrapper@5f39cb`

Comment: Sorry, but can you rephrase it?

Answer (score 2):

Check spell of get-er in wrapper class it should be something like this

```
public List<FLTQuestionnaireBean> getQuestionnaireBeanList{
return myQuestionnaireBeanList
};
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response and I checked it and Yes it is like that.